# Spring Boot @Retryable Mock Test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have a code block like below:

```java
    @Service
    ExecutorService {

    @Autowired
    IAccountService accountService;

        @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, value = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2))
        public void execute(RequestDto reqDto)
        {
            Account acc = accountService.getAccount(reqDto.getAccountId);
            ...
        }
    }
```

In Mockito test, I just want to see call method 3 times as expected.

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class CampaignExecuterServiceTest
    {
        private static final Long ACCOUNT_ID = 1L;

        @InjectMocks
        private ExecutorService executorService;

        @Mock
        private IAccountService accountService;

        @Test
        public void execute_success()
        {
            Account account = new Account(ACCOUNT_ID, null, null, null, null);
            RequestDto reqDto = new RequestDto();
            when(accountService.getAccount(any())).thenThrow(DataIntegrityViolationException.class);
            executorService.execute(reqDto);
            verify(executorService, times(3)).execute(any());
        }
    }
```

Test just throws an exception. But I expected it to call it 3 times.

Comment: Mock and InjectMocks are Mockito annotations. They're used by Mockito if you use the Mockito runner (but you don't), or if you use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() (but I guess you don't). So executorService and accountService are both null, so you get an NPE. Even if Mockito did initialize these two variables, since Spring isn't used at all, it can't retry anything. You need a Spring integration test, with Spring beans, i.e with Autowired and MockBean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

1) `@SpringBootTest` is need to create a Spring Boot app runner that will intercept your retryable method. JUnit won't do that on its own. Also, the `classes` param needs to be your main class in place of `MainApplication` or a subset of classes that can run as a Spring boot app.

2) `ExecutorService` must be annotated with `@Autowired` so it will be the bean from the Spring boot application the test is creating.

3) `IAccountService` must be a `@MockBean` that is how the test Spring boot environment will know to use a mocked class in `ExecutorService` instead of the real bean.

4) In the test the third mock call needs to return a valid result or it will throw an exception and the test will fail. Alternately, you could catch the exception in the test.

5) `ExecutorService` is not a mock or spy so `verify` will not accept it as an arg at runtime, but `accountService` is a mock so just assert it is called 3 times.

Another note is that somewhere in the Spring boot config or on the `MainApplication` you must have the `@EnableRetry` annotation.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MainApplication.class)
public class CampaignExecuterServiceTest {
    private static final Long ACCOUNT_ID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @MockBean
    private IAccountService accountService;

    @Test
    public void execute_success() {
        Account account = new Account(ACCOUNT_ID, null, null, null, null);;
        RequestDto reqDto = new RequestDto();
        when(accountService.getAccount(any()))
                .thenThrow(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
                .thenThrow(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
                .thenReturn(account);
        executorService.execute(reqDto);
        verify(accountService, times(3)).getAccount(any());
    }
}
```